# What is a hook in the testing Nestjs framework context?

Tags: testing, hook, nestjs

I am trying to grasp how to test well with Nestjs.

Therefore I am reading the documentation [https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#testing-utilities], but there is this extract that I don't fully understand :

> The Test class is useful for providing an application execution context that essentially mocks the full Nest runtime, but gives you **hooks** that make it easy to manage class instances, including mocking and overriding.

What is a hook in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, there are two major hooks that are being generally references:

1. The `Test.createTestingModule().compile()` command. This allows us to set up a test module with minimum effort so we can pass in only the metadata required for the class we want to test. Instead of having to add a module to an `imports` we can pass the service to `providers` along with custom providers to mock that service's dependencies. This makes unit testing much easier (in my opinion). This also makes it possible to not have to call `new MyService(new MockDep1(), new MockDep2(), ...new MockDepN())` and Nest will still manage it for us, as it has been doing.
2. The `TestingModule` also has a few useful chainable methods like `overridePrivoder`, `overrideGuard`, `overrideInterceptor`, `overridePipe`, and `overrideFilter`. These allow us to override providers and enhancers that are already set up in the context of the module (say, if we're using imports for e2e tests)